# Trying to create an instance of an abstract contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, error

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';

contract SubToken{
    mapping(address => uint) balances;

    string  symbol;
    string  name;
    uint8  decimals;
    uint  totalSupply; 

    using SafeMath for uint;

    //subtoken_struct public sub_tokens;

    //mapping(address  => subtoken_struct) public mySubTokens ;

    address contract_address; 

    constructor(string memory _name,string memory _symbol,uint8 _decimals,uint256 _totalSupply)  public{ 
        name = _name; 
        symbol = _symbol; 
        decimals=_decimals; 
        totalSupply = _totalSupply; 
        balances[msg.sender]=_totalSupply; 
    } 
    //function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
    //function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
    //function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
    //function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) ;
    //function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);

}
contract MainContrat {
    mapping(address => uint) balances;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;
    mapping(address => address[]) public created;

    mapping(address => SubToken) public tokenlist;

    address[] public contracts;
    address owner = msg.sender;

    using SafeMath for uint;

    address contract_address;

    function createNewContract(string memory _name,string memory _symbol,uint8 _decimals,uint256 _totalSupply) public returns(address newAddres){ 
        SubToken mc = new SubToken(_name,_symbol,_decimals,_totalSupply); 
        created[msg.sender].push(address(mc)); 
        contracts.push(address(mc)); 
        return address(mc); 
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

}
```

hey guys I have a main contract and have a creteContract function. This function create a new subtoken so I use subToken like a interface.

when I compile my contract I got a error like this :

> **TypeError: Trying to create an instance of an abstract contract. SubToken mc = new SubToken(_name,_symbol,_decimals,_totalSupply); 
>   ^----------^ browser/crtcont7.sol:32:5: Missing implementation:
>   function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public
>   returns (bool success);
>   ^-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^**

Comment: The title alone implies that you have some basic misunderstanding of the term *abstract*. You cannot instantiate an abstract object. This is true not only for Solidity, but for any other object-oriented language.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but can you write correct contract or just re-design my contact again please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0; 
import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol'; 

contract SubToken{ 
    mapping(address => uint) balances; 

    string  symbol; 
    string  name; 
    uint8  decimals; 
    uint  totalSupply;  

    using SafeMath for uint; 

    address contract_address;  

    constructor(string memory _name,string memory _symbol,uint8 _decimals,uint256 _totalSupply)  public{  
        name = _name;  
        symbol = _symbol;  
        decimals=_decimals;  
        totalSupply = _totalSupply;  
        balances[msg.sender]=_totalSupply;  
    }  

    //function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success); 
    //function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);  
    //function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) ;  
    //function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);  
    //function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);  

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens); 
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens); 

} 
contract MainContract { 
    mapping(address => uint) balances; 

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed; 
    mapping(address => address[]) public created; 

    mapping(address => SubToken) public tokenlist; 

    address[] public contracts; 
    address owner = msg.sender; 

    using SafeMath for uint; 

    address contract_address; 
    /* 

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) { 
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value); 
        return true; 
    } 
    */ 
    function createNewContract(string memory _name,string memory _symbol,uint8 _decimals,uint256 _totalSupply) public returns(address){  
        SubToken st = new SubToken(_name,_symbol,_decimals,_totalSupply); 
         //st = new SubToken();  
        created[msg.sender].push(address(st));  
        contracts.push(address(st));  
        //return address(mc);  
    }  
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value); 
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value); 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [OpenZeppelin Contracts ERC20 Token documentation](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/tokens#ERC20) to see if this meets your needs for an ERC20 Token.  You may also want to use the [OpenZeppelin IERC20 interface](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20).

Note that you should only use OpenZeppelin code published in an official release, so you should include the version tag in your import when using Remix or you can take a look at the [Getting Started guide](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/) for information on how to setup a development environment.

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.3.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

You can also ask questions about how to use OpenZeppelin Contracts in the [Community Forum](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/)

Disclosure: I am the the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin